# Python Object Comparisons

Tags: python

I need to override object comparisons so that I can compare instances of classes using < > == != <= >= operators.  Does python have any methods that I use to do so.

Comment: You should try and make your question a bit more narrow and clear. In one or two sentences, what is it that you're actually asking?

Comment: Im asking how do I override the < > != == and such comparisons so that I can compare objects

Comment: @AnatoliySokolov CSE 130 is leaking.. I'm not sure what you're asking, it looks like you have already implemented the necessary methods to override the operators.

Comment: @AnatoliySokolov Don't just update your existing question with the fixed solution. You can, if you want to, add a note such as "**Update:** I solved the issue using the following code: `...`". That's not a valid answer though, and if one of the current answers helped you to get to your solution, even if it doesn't provide the fixed code, you should accept it. If none of the answers helped, you can always post your own answer and accept that one. I've reverted your update to your main post.

Comment: Ok Ill do that from now on.  And Ill actually change my questions to have less code in them so I dont leak it to CSE 130.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What Im not sure about is what methods I need to use to compare the vectors. I tried googling it but couldn't find anything. Does python have some methods to override < > <= and so on?

Yes, Python has magic methods which are exactly for this purpose. You're already using magic methods, such as `__len__`, `__iter__`, etc. [Here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#comparisons)'s a good link for the comparison magic methods, you're particularly looking for:

- `__eq__` = **eq**ual to (`==`)
- `__ne__` = **n**ot **e**qual to (`!=`)
- `__lt__` = **l**ess **t**han (`<`)
- `__le__` = **l**ess than or **e**qual to (`<=`)
- `__gt__` = **g**reater **t**han (`>`)
- `__ge__` = **g**reater than or **e**qual to (`>=`)

Answer (score 0):

The magic methods in question are:

- `__lt__` -> less than
- `__le__` -> less than or equal
- `__ge__` -> greater than or equal
- `__gt__` -> greater than

and, of course,

- `__eq__` -> equal to
- `__ne__` -> not equal to

The basic framework for each of those methods is:

```
def __xx__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        return NotImplemented
    # working code here
```

Those first two lines (after the `def`) will ensure that your objects work correctly with subclasses as well as other random objects.

Comment: for my case only vectors are allowed to be passed in and nonvectors are for ne and eq but if they are I just say they arent equal, updated the code with a working solution.